# Make Embedded Video Use all Available HTML Element Width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an embeded Youtube Video that sits inside a `td` HTML element. I am attempting to get the video to have the width of it's parent `td` element but still keep its aspect ratio (aspect adjusted height).

I am attempting to get the video size to look like this:
[image]

My problem is that the video looks like this:
[image]

How can I use CSS to make the video to scale up to use all the available width of the `td` element **BUT still keep its aspect ratio**?

Heres my code and heres my [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/UZMc2/):

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 450px;">
            <!-- Note the Youtube video is loaded using the Youtube Javscript API-->
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zrWkRHSK6A8?enablejsapi=1" style="width: auto; height: auto;"></iframe>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You said you are attempting to get the video size to look like this?? Where is it..?? did you forgot to insert something???

Comment: @Kaushik can you see the screen capture (image) underneath the text "I am attempting to get the video size to look like this:"?

Comment: The problem is that your webpage doesn't know about the properties of a contents of a different webpage (which is what the content of the iframe is). The best solution is to simply fill in the desired size manually. If you're using Javascript anyway, just calculate the dimensions from the width and height of the td.

Comment: No dude.. There is no image under that sentence...

Comment: @Kaushik dude, check your firewall or ad-blocking. There are two images in the question.

Comment: @MrLister Sorry guys.. may be my network problem.. I am using company's network and they might have blocked the things.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the iframe a max-width and apply the td with a percentage based width as well!

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UZMc2/1/)

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 50%;">
            <!-- Note the Youtube video is loaded using the Youtube Javscript API-->
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zrWkRHSK6A8?enablejsapi=1" style="max-width: 100%;height: 100%;"></iframe>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ansciath/B8FU8/1127/) will give you some basic idea about how to resize your video, while sticking to its aspect ratio (fiddle not by me).

There is an article about it [here](http://ansciath.tumblr.com/post/7347495869/css-aspect-ratio), that you might want to have a look at.

Basically, what he does is add a dummy `<div>` and use the `padding-top:75%;` (the value is for an aspect ratio of 4:3. You must adjust it to fit your desired aspect ratio).

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the aspect ratio of the video, you can use [the Intrinsic Ratios for Video technique outlined on A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video).

Basically, you put a `div` inside the `td` element. Make it `position: relative` and use `padding` to make it the right height, e.g. for 16:9 (with a 25px control bar):

```
div.videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}
```

Put the youtube iframe inside the div, and set `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%;` on it, e.g.

```
iframe[src*=['youtube.com/embed/'] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```